# Magento Turpentine Varnish not working properly

Tags: php, magento, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

Below is the Header of my site it is a Magento Website with Turpentine installed, it is showing the Varnish Hit, but the Age Headers are not showing up and it is showing "**Sortof**" on [Here](http://www.isvarnishworking.com). Kindly Help on this!

**Request Header**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:www.xyz.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://www.xyz.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36
```

**Response Header**

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 31 Jan 2014 06:46:22 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Via:1.1 varnish
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
X-Turpentine-Cache:1
X-Turpentine-Esi:1
X-Varnish:751218804 751214783
X-Varnish-Currency:
X-Varnish-Esi-Access:
X-Varnish-Esi-Method:
X-Varnish-Hits:5
X-Varnish-Set-Cookie:frontend=6417b8aee0944094808f0b75335c84f3; expires=Fri, 31-Jan-2014 07:39:55 GMT; path=/; domain=www.alldaychemist.com; httponly
X-Varnish-Store:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Age` response header is removed intentionally by the Magneto Turpentine plugin.  You can see its Varnish configuration template here:

https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/misc/version-3.vcl#L279

Here is the relevant excerpt:

```
        # we'll set our own cache headers if we need them
        unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
        unset beresp.http.Expires;
        unset beresp.http.Pragma;
        unset beresp.http.Cache;
        unset beresp.http.Age;
```

In short, it's working as intended and there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Andy, So how to check whether the Varnish is working perfectly Fine and our configuration is proper.